# topology of kolmogroff space

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a Kolmogoroff space. Show that $x\in \overline{\{x'\}}$ is an order relation between $x$ and $x'$ in $X$. and that if this relation is written as $x\leq x'$ then given topology on $X$ is identical to right topology ($[x,\rightarrow[$) determined by this ordering. I have proved the first part($x\in \overline{\{x'\}}$ is ordered), but how to show the identical relation with right topology.

Comment: Perhaps include a link to the definition of "kolmogoroff space".

Comment: A topological space is said to be a Kolmogoroff space if it satisfies the following condition: given any two distinct points x, x' of X, there is a neighbourhood of one of these points which does not contain the other.

Comment: This is now commonly called a $T_0$ space.

Answer (score 0):

That is impossible.  Consider the set S with two different Hausdorff topologies.  They are both Kolmogroff spaces.
They have the same order, namely x <= y iff x = y.
As they are different topologies, one of them cannot be
homeomorphic to the right topology of that order.

Comment: the identity is not even a linear order (which is what's usually assumed for the right topology). I offer another interpretation in my answer, which might come closer to the intention of the text the OP is (wrongly?) quoting.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma.  To rescue the problem, the order does not have to be linear and the space is finite.  There is only one T1 topology for a finite set.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is incompletely formulated, I think. If $X$ is a Kolmogorov (a.k.a $T_0$) space then indeed $x \le y$ iff $x \in \overline{\{y\}}$ is a *partial* order (the so-called specialisation order). In fact, it's a pre-order (reflexive and transitive) in *any* space but the $T_0$ property ensures the antisymmetry: $x \le y$ and $\le x$ implies $x=y$.

But the Bourbaki problem quoted in the comments (General Topology, Chapter 1, p. 117 problem 2c) is for an Alexandrov space, a space where the intersection of *any* family of open sets is open! (it's somewhat hidden in the beginning and Bourbaki does not call it this). In that case the stated result does hold:

Define for each $x \in X$, the set $M_x = \bigcap \{O\mid x \in O \text{ open } \}$ the minimal open set containing $x$ (it's open because we have an Alexandrov space). $x \le y$ iff $y \in M_x$ (iff every open set containing $x$ contains $y$) and the $T_0$ property ensures that $x \neq y$ implies that $M_x \neq M_y$. In that case it is indeed not too hard to show that $X$ has the upper topology wrt this partial order $\le$. E.g. $[x,\rightarrow)=M_x$ is open and every open set $O$ of $X$ is the union of the minimal neighbourhoods of its elements, so upper-open too.

The arbitrary intersection property makes a big difference...

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89362/discussion-on-answer-by-henno-brandsma-topology-of-kolmogroff-space).